# update api not updating db in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i tryed to make a update api in larvel in post man i am gettng 200 but the reponce of api is same as the old data and api does not update

what i have tryed is this

```
Route::patch('/update', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) { 

// Validate the incoming data 

$data = $request->validate([
    'name' => '|max:255',
    'phone'=> 'max:255',
    'email' => '|email|unique:users',
    'period'=> 'max:255',
    'babyname'=> 'max:255',
    'baby_date'=> 'max:255',
  ]);
  
  // Retrieve the authenticated user
  $user = auth()->user(); 


// Update the user's fields with the new data
  $user->update($data);
  
  // Return a JSON response with the updated user data
  return new \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse(['user' => $user] , 200);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

as u can see in screen shot the data although it is 200 the responce is same old data and data is not updated in db

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your model check $fillable array

Comment: @Zia can u explain

Comment: check what returns $user->update($data);

Comment: @menucd show me your User.php file

Comment: The attributes that you are trying to update need to be in the [$fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) property in an the User model.

Comment: @Zia how do i post full file here

Comment: update your answer

Comment: @Zia i added screen shot

Comment: you have error in your code let me Anser for you

Comment: oke i will wait

Comment: $user = $request()->all();

Comment: check the updated answer you are updating the answer with current values of user not from request you need to get values from $request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250804/discussion-between-menu-cd-and-zia).

Comment: @Zia is there any way u can help me?

Comment: check new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::patch('/update', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) { 

// Validate the incoming data 

$data = $request->validate([
    'name' => '|max:255',
    'phone'=> 'max:255',
    'email' => '|email|unique:users',
    'period'=> 'max:255',
    'babyname'=> 'max:255',
    'baby_date'=> 'max:255',
  ]);
  
  // Retrieve the authenticated user
  $user = auth()->user(); 
  $data = $request->all();
  $user->fill($data);
// Update the user's fields with the new data
  $user->save();
  
  // Return a JSON response with the updated user data
  return new \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse(['user' => $user] , 200);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: still no luck the db is same and respoce is same

Comment: @brombeer pls add a answer and explain i am not sure where i should add this

Comment: i think, @brombeer `$request->validated()` will only work for Dedicated request correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Correct, my fault, `$request->validated()` seems to be for when you're using a form request or a manually created validator instance. Will remove my comments

Comment: @brombeer  is there any way u can help me

Comment: @Zia is there any way u can help me